# How to filter a data table with each items in a object using RowFilter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, datatable

I have a data table and I can  filter it like this.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-DATE]='{0}'", "03/12/16");//step ONE
```

this returns result successfully.

now I have a object like this

```
var myObject = returnPorts(one).Split('|');
```

this `myObject` includes **5** items. so I want to filter above `DataTable` for all items in the `myObject`.I don't know how to do that.need like this

```
 dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT]='{0}'", "Should filter with all the items in the myObject at once");//step TWO
```

want your help with this. and other thing is I want to do **step ONE** and **step TWO** at once.need the help for that also. thank you very much.

Comment: yes sure. first step is fiter for date and step two is filter with ports.appcireate your help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete answer. `@freedomn-m's` answer helped me lot.thank your very much.

**For the first part(filter with any number of items in the object).thanx to   @freedomn-m**

```
var parts = returnPorts(one).Split('|');
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT] IN ('{0}')", String.Join("','", parts));
```

**For part two - to concate any number of conditions**

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT] IN  ('{0}') AND [CRUISE-ONLY]=('{1}') AND [SAILING-DATE]=('{2}')", String.Join("','", threee), "YES", "03/12/16");
```

thanx all, who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

RowFilter uses as fairly basic syntax but does allow you to use `IN`:

```
var parts = returnPorts(one).Split('|');
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT] IN ('{0}')", String.Join("','", parts));
```

to combine this with the date, either add it to `parts` or, cleaner, to the format:

```
var parts = returnPorts(one).Split('|');
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT] IN ('{0}', '{1}')", 
                             "03/12/16", 
                             String.Join("','", parts));
```

Comment: your first part is correct and very nice. but in second section, `[SAILING-PORT]` and `[SAILING-DATE]` both are two different columns in the table.I want to concat both with `AND`.as an exmple like this `dv.RowFilter = "[CRUISE-ONLY]='YES' AND [NOW-AVAIL]='YES' AND [1A] <> 'N/A'";`

Answer (score 0):

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[SAILING-PORT] in ('{0}')", string.Join(" ',' ", myObject ));
```

this will concatenate all the values from the array into single string. This will allow you to filter all the values from in the array.

Comment: Close, but look at what the IN clause will be generated as with that code...  `in ('a,b,c')` which is a single filter value

Comment: need to add single quote at both sides of the comma.